# ng-repeater not working for JSON

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

here is my JSON

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"54357d7f62042c439bfd6279"},"imageType":"Image/jpg","Heading":"Test Heading","Description":"Test Discription","Image":"","created_at":"","infoType":"QuickInfo"},{"_id":{"$oid":"54357eb862042c439bfd627a"},"imageType":"Image/png","Heading":"Test Heading 2","Description":"Test Discription 2","Image":"","created_at":"","infoType":"QuickInfo"}]
```

my repeater

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="fact in facts track by $index" href="#/app/fact/{{fact._id}}">
    {{fact.Heading}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Error:
It has populated a lot of empty list items.

HELP!!

Comment: Could you show us the code from your controller ?
(specifically where you put the json in your array "facts")

Why do you use "track by $index" in your ng-repeat ?

Comment: I was getting error saying duplicate data not allowed. So indexed it. I am fetching the json from mongolabs, storing it in localStorage and then setting it in $scope.facts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working ok.

```
    $scope.facts=[
    {
        "_id":{"$oid":"54357d7f62042c439bfd6279"},
        "imageType":"Image/jpg",
        "Heading":"Test Heading",
        "Description":"Test Discription",
        "Image":"",
        "created_at":"",
        "infoType":"QuickInfo"
    },
    {
        "_id":{"$oid":"54357eb862042c439bfd627a"},
        "imageType":"Image/png",
        "Heading":"Test Heading 2",
        "Description":"Test Discription 2",
        "Image":"","created_at":"","infoType":"QuickInfo"
    }
];

<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="fact in facts track by $index" href="#/app/fact/{{fact._id}}">
    {{fact.Heading}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Also if you get the data back as JSON you can do

```
$scope.facts=JSON.parse(json_string);
```