# ng-repeat track by $index returning no results in ionic cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Using the browser, both firefox and chrome, I am able to see my repeated items. However once the app is pushed to the device (android in this case) no results show. I am sure it is iterating through the total results, because I get a blank screen with 51 blank  spots. If I don't use the [track by $index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed) I get the duplicate error.

I attempted the json.parse(); found here [ng-repeater not working for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272629/ng-repeater-not-working-for-json) with no results either.

My controller looks like so:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http) {
    $http.get('/js/center-forecast.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.jsondatas = data.rows;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.jsondatas = "Error. The Report is Not Available at this Time.";
    });
});
```

Loop:

```
<ion-list>
                    <ion-item ng-repeat="jsondata in jsondatas track by $index">
                        {{jsondata.row.name}}

                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
```

EDIT: Just tried {{$index.jsondata.row.name}} and got the same results as the device in the browser. 51 rows with no data.

.json data validates just fine. It is repeating through on the device, but not showing the results in each , just showing a blank . I did check the css to make sure the words are not white. I don't see any results/errors in log.cat either...

Any ideas?

edit: JSON data example:

```
"rows": [{
        "row": {
            "id": "AAIC",
            "name": "Alaska Avalanche",
            "url": "http://www.valdezavalanchecenter.org",
            "center_point": "(-146.3053,61.1231)",
            "lat": "61.1231",
            "lng": "-146.3053",
            "icon": "center_i.gif"
        }
    }, {
        "row": {
            "id": "PAC",
            "name": "Payette",
            "url": "http://www.payetteavalanche.org/advisory/",
            "center_point": "(-116.095276,44.906469)",
            "lat": "44.906469",
            "lng": "-116.095276",
            "icon": "center.png"
        }
    }, {
        "row": {
            "id": "KPAC",
            "name": "Flagstaff/Kachina Peaks",
            "url": "http://www.kachinapeaks.org/",
            "center_point": "(-111.6506,35.1981)",
            "lat": "35.1981",
            "lng": "-111.6506",
            "icon": "center_i.gif"
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Did you get json in console

Comment: This is my console output: Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 41 more… ]... and then the arrays contain the objects with the correct data.

Comment: Just to check if the navigator is creating 0px-height items, try to do something lik <div style="height: 20px; width: 30px">{{jsondata.row.name}}</div>

Comment: If i add {{$index}} in there i get numbers. So text does show... Just not the results from the json file. Only once deployed to the device.  Browser is fine... Strange stuff